# Reported speech for things not related with communication

Tags: grammar, sentence-choice, reported-speech

Which of these sentences would be correct?

"Currently we've got no clue how consciousness works."

Or

"Currently we've got no clue how consciousness worked."

Comment: I don't see this as "reported speech". Can you explain why you see this as a type of reported speech?

Comment: @JamesK We were told by our English teacher that reported speech includes a broad range of subordinate clauses. What about: "I signalled to him, he was an idiot." - would that be ok?

Comment: **Signaled** is a form of expression and communication.  It could be basis for reported speech.  *She signaled  to us he was just kidding.*

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo Thank you, what about my example? In yours, it's not clear whether the subject of the signal was "he is just kidding" or "he was just kidding"

Comment: As James K said, there's no reason to see your sentence as reported speech. There's no report of  someone expressing something.  *Early cosmologies told their audiences little about how the universe worked.*   *19th century pscyhologists had some crazy ideas about how consciousnesss worked.*

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo Yes, I acknowledged my wrong assumption. Now I'm just wondering if things like "signalling" still count. So what's the correct version: "I signaled to him he was an idiot." OR "I signaled to him he is an idiot." ? Thanks

Comment: Do idiots stop being idiots?  *She said he was an idiot*.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo So "I signaled to him he is an idiot." , right?

Comment: I don't know what you're trying to say. *I signaled to him he was an idiot* is how you would report the signaling.  *I told him he was an idiot*. He is probably still an idiot. *I told him he had been an idiot*.  Perhaps he has mended his ways.  *I told Harry Potter he had been acting like an idiot.* "Harry, you've been acting like an idiot" were my exact words.

Comment: You can say *They **had** no clue how consciousness **worked***. You seem to be deliberately going against the underlying notion of "reported" with "Currently".

Comment: Let's say the message of the signaling was "you're an idiot". Would I report it as: _I signaled to him he was an idiot_?

Answer (score 2):

The correct sentence would be:

> "Currently we've got no clue how consciousness **works**."

The reason for this is that the second sentence uses the past tense of work.
This would imply that consciousness once *worked*, but no longer *works*, which we know is false.

Answer (score 2):

The sentence here are not "reported speech" even if that has a wide meaning.

A sentence with reported speech has a verb of saying: "said", "asked", "thought" and so on and the reported information may be backshifted or have a change of perspective. The tense in the reported idea is put into the past tense to match the tense in the main clause

> We believed that consciousness worked like a computer.

Your sentence isn't like this. There is a main clause

> We have no clue []

and a subordinate clause

> [how consciousness works]

But this isn't the reporting of speech or belief.